# How to expand a textarea on focus over the top of other items using jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

This has been answered many times and many ways for divs and images but I can't find an example of how to do this for a `textarea`.

I want the `textarea` to expand and not move the other items below it, but to expand over the top of them. I have a working example below of simply expanding it, but I want, if I can get it, to animate the expansion not just snap it larger and smaller.

I don't want to use `position: absolute` nor do I want to use some other html element other than a `textarea`. I need this all to work in a table as well, which my html below shows.

This is my html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><textarea class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Here is some text just below. I want it to not move.</td>
<tr>
<tr>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt1').focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass('focused');
    });
    $('#txt1').blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('focused');
    });
});
```

And my CSS:

```
.focused {
    position: relative;
    height: 10em !important;
    z-index: 1000;
}

textarea {
    width: 350px;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Choose one: a `table` with `position: absolute;` or a `div` with `float: left`...

From what I can see, with the decision to use a table, must use `positon: absolute;` because you need to use `z-index:` and flow-over other elements. Using `float: left` along with a `table` will clear floats. Otherwise you could use `float: left` pretty easily.

**See working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/JdA6L/

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass("expanding")
        $(this).animate({
            height: "10em"
        }, 500);
    });
    $('textarea.expand').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "1em"
        }, 500);
        $(this).removeClass("expanding")
    });
});
```

Added one CSS class:

```
.expanding {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I remember doing everything around this but didn't quite get there. Perfect solution.

Comment: Now here's the rub, while it works beautifully as a regular old html file, the same code transplaced into an MVC 4 application does not expand over the top of items below, which is of course the place I intended this example to go all along. I just didn't think I should to there. To complicate the whole thing, I am also adding a TinyMCE editor on the textarea. Got expertise in that arena?

Comment: That's a separate question entirely. Yes, I know the factors brought by TinyMCE, but please start a new question, accept this answer, link to this question, and post the link here also. Entirely different situation, but it'll be solved now that the full situation is explained as you have.